# XPath incorrect query path

Tags: php, xml, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xpath fails if an element has a a xmlns attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285570/xpath-fails-if-an-element-has-a-a-xmlns-attribute)

I have been trying for a long time to extract a string from the following xml with no luck
http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm?state=8T

I am trying to get the ASIN number of a book and I have tried

```
$xpath->query('//MarketplaceASIN/ASIN')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

and

```
$xpath->query('/GetMatchingProductResponse/GetMatchingProductResult[1]/Product/Identifiers/MarketplaceASIN/ASIN')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

but neither seem to work, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in that document are bound to the namespace `http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01`.

You may have missed it because it does not use a namespace-prefix and the `xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01"` just looks like an attribute, but namespace attributes are special.

All of the descendant elements inherit that namespace. You will want to register the namespace with a namespace-prefix and adjust your XPath:

```
$rootNamespace = $xml->lookupNamespaceUri($xml->namespaceURI); 
$xpath->registerNamespace('a', $rootNamespace); 
$elementList = $xpath->query('//a:MarketplaceASIN/a:ASIN');
```

---

Or you could use a more generic XPath that matches on elements and uses a predicate filter to match the `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()`:

```
//*[local-name()='MarketplaceASIN' and namespace-uri()='http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01']/*[local-name()='ASIN' and namespace-uri()='http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01']
```

Comment: thank you so much, thats 5 hours of sleep I won't get back