# DOM XPath Query Help

Tags: php, dom, xpath

so this xpath query is driving me crazy. What I'm trying to do is search an xml file (in this case a kml file for use with the google maps api) of golf courses for a specific course type and grab each matching `<Placemark>` element so that i can create a new xml object with the results so that I can further filter with a new query. Problem is I can't seem to figure out how to get each matching `<Placemark>` element

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
    <Document>
      <Placemark id="placemark3">
          <name>Test Country Club</name>
          <description>
              <![CDATA[
                 <div class="contact">Post Office Box 329 <a href="#" target="_blank">website</a></div>
              ]]>
          </description>
          <alpha>a</alpha>
          <position>2</position>
          <type>Public/Daily Fee</type>
          <styleUrl>#nineholeStyle</styleUrl>
          <Point>
              <coordinates>-79.285576,37.111809</coordinates>
          </Point>
      </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//trying to get any Placemark element where type child matches a specific query
//in this case we want to search for Public/Daily Fee and return the placemark and everything inside it.
$query = $xpath->query("//Placemark[type='Public/Daily Fee']/ancestor::Placemark");;

  foreach ($query as $result) {
    //eventually want to merge each result into new xml object to be further filtered
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading KML file in to mysql / xpath and x quires](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341039/loading-kml-file-in-to-mysql-xpath-and-x-quires)

Comment: @Alejando true, but it doesnt have an answer. Should probably be merged then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You did not [register the XML namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php) before the query.

```
// register it
$xpath->registerNamespace('kml', "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1");

// and use it, too !
$query = $xpath->query("//kml:Placemark[kml:type='Public/Daily Fee']");
```

*(the `ancestor::kml:Placemark` in your expression made no sense, I left it out.)*

The namespace prefix in the XPath query must be used even if the namespace in question is the *default namespace* of the XML document (like in your case).

The element `<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">` is equivalent to `<kml:kml xmlns:kml="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1"`>.

However, an XPath query of `/kml` is not equivalent to `/kml:kml`. The latter would match both elements (when the `kml` namespace is registered beforehand), the former would match none of them, no matter what you do.

Also note that you do not *need* to use the same namespace prefix that is used in the XML document.

Assume the XML document is this:

```
<kml:kml xmlns:kml="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
  <kml:Document />
</kml:kml>
```

Then you could still do this:

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('foo', "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1");
$query = $xpath->query("/foo:kml/foo:Document");
```

and get back a correct result. Namespace prefixes are just a shorthand.

Comment: Ahhh thanks. But was the initial query right? I'm not getting any results, should i just be using $result->saveXML?

Comment: @Jamie: I've changed the XPath in my answer, I forgot the `kml` prefix at one point myself. Should work now. Also note that you do not need the `ancestor::` part at all.