# Handling XML specific data

Tags: php, xml

Hi im using this XML format, saved after a WSDL web service.

```
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd" version="3.2" fecha="2014-04-25T06:01:38" total="15" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" metodoDePago="Transferencia" LugarExpedicion="PUEBLA, PUEBLA" sello="JiIQekdlpaLJ67Ikm/AJtLCapHRWEYajyug1TaHCd9wRAPtalkzv4YPBWxZwesWS4jfHK9yC2csyAOedy+FsjtTtgonKNfk6wr55YtSXuM0wHGXLvqRHpsIUoppqktL6TFDGyZvmxTyFLHQyZMTSZhBYofnXhXmy8+SoMXfa/Ws=" noCertificado="20001000000100005867" certificado="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" subTotal="$ 12<sup>93</sup>" formaDePago="PAGO EN UNA SOLA EXHIBICION" serie="47" folio="47" descuento="00.00" condicionesDePago="PAGO EN UNA SOLA EXHIBICION" Moneda="MXN">
<cfdi:Emisor rfc="AAA010101AAA" nombre="CLICK FACTURA SA DE CV">
<cfdi:DomicilioFiscal calle="25 PTE" municipio="PUEBLA" estado="PUEBLA" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="72580" noExterior="913" noInterior="E" colonia="CHULAVISTA"/>
<cfdi:ExpedidoEn pais="MEXICO" noExterior="13" colonia="SAN MANUEL" calle="14 SUR" municipio="PUEBLA" estado="PUEBLA" codigoPostal="72000"/>
<cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="REGIMEN GENERAL DE LEY"/>
</cfdi:Emisor>
<cfdi:Receptor rfc="CAJR"·$"5IP1" nombre="Ramon">
<cfdi:Domicilio pais="MEXICO" calle="Circuito " noExterior="75" noInterior="23" colonia="Loma Linda" municipio="Queretaro" estado="QuerÃ©taro" codigoPostal="76070"/>
</cfdi:Receptor>
<cfdi:Conceptos>
<cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1" unidad="NO APLICA" descripcion="ComisiÃ³n por la venta de 1 Celular iphone 3 por un total de $ 10 pesos M.N." valorUnitario="15.000000" importe="15.000000"/>
</cfdi:Conceptos>
<cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosTrasladados="$ 2<sup>07</sup>">
<cfdi:Traslados>
<cfdi:Traslado impuesto="IVA" tasa="16" importe="15"/>
</cfdi:Traslados>
</cfdi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

Im using this to handle the xml , and display info

http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/handling-xml-data

My code look something like here:

```
if (file_exists("xml/".$xml_file_name)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("xml/".$xml_file_name);

    //print_r($xml);
    //echo $xml['folio'];
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("xml/".$xml_file_name, null, true);

} else {
    exit('Error al abrir el archivo xml.');
}

    echo $xml['fecha'];
        echo $xml->Receptor['nombre'];
```

`$xml['fecha']` its echoing ok. i get the date.

I cant figure out how to echo this `$xml->Receptor['nombre'];`

this part

```
    <cfdi:Receptor rfc="CAJR"·$"5IP1" nombre="Ramon">
<cfdi:Domicilio pais="MEXICO" calle="Circuito " noExterior="75" noInterior="23" colonia="Loma Linda" municipio="Queretaro" estado="QuerÃ©taro" codigoPostal="76070"/>
</cfdi:Receptor>
```

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412047/parse-xml-namespaces-with-php-simplexml

Comment: Thanks its just what im looking for, the sad stuff, is i cant make it work because of the "2 levels" using both : , if this where "wraped" in a element without points, i think this should be already running, =(. so frustrated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!, Finally i get the rigth answer to my syntax problem

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Receptor') as $Receptor){ 
   $Receptor_rfc = $Receptor['rfc']; 

   $Receptor_nombre = $Receptor['nombre']; 

}
```

And then a comun and simple echo on that `$Receptor_nombre` and thats it