# php : How to parse XML containing ":" in node names using simplexml_load_file?

Tags: php, xml-parsing

My XML has that content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<education:education xmlns:address="http://www.orcid.org/ns/address" xmlns:email="http://www.orcid.org/ns/email" xmlns:history="http://www.orcid.org/ns/history" xmlns:employment="http://www.orcid.org/ns/employment" xmlns:education="http://www.orcid.org/ns/education" xmlns:other-name="http://www.orcid.org/ns/other-name" xmlns:deprecated="http://www.orcid.org/ns/deprecated" xmlns:funding="http://www.orcid.org/ns/funding" xmlns:research-resource="http://www.orcid.org/ns/research-resource" xmlns:service="http://www.orcid.org/ns/service" xmlns:researcher-url="http://www.orcid.org/ns/researcher-url" xmlns:distinction="http://www.orcid.org/ns/distinction" xmlns:internal="http://www.orcid.org/ns/internal" xmlns:membership="http://www.orcid.org/ns/membership" xmlns:person="http://www.orcid.org/ns/person" xmlns:personal-details="http://www.orcid.org/ns/personal-details" xmlns:bulk="http://www.orcid.org/ns/bulk" xmlns:common="http://www.orcid.org/ns/common" xmlns:record="http://www.orcid.org/ns/record" xmlns:keyword="http://www.orcid.org/ns/keyword" xmlns:activities="http://www.orcid.org/ns/activities" xmlns:qualification="http://www.orcid.org/ns/qualification" xmlns:external-identifier="http://www.orcid.org/ns/external-identifier" xmlns:error="http://www.orcid.org/ns/error" xmlns:preferences="http://www.orcid.org/ns/preferences" xmlns:invited-position="http://www.orcid.org/ns/invited-position" xmlns:work="http://www.orcid.org/ns/work" xmlns:peer-review="http://www.orcid.org/ns/peer-review" put-code="2205086" path="/0000-0001-5010-5001/education/2205086" display-index="0" visibility="public">
    <common:created-date>2016-09-01T19:20:47.076Z</common:created-date>
    <common:last-modified-date>2016-09-01T19:20:47.076Z</common:last-modified-date>
    <common:source>
        <common:source-orcid>
            <common:uri>https://orcid.org/0000-0001-5010-5001</common:uri>
            <common:path>0000-0001-5010-5001</common:path>
            <common:host>orcid.org</common:host>
        </common:source-orcid>
        <common:source-name>Quang Nguyen</common:source-name>
    </common:source>
    <common:end-date>
        <common:year>2012</common:year>
        <common:month>05</common:month>
    </common:end-date>
    <common:organization>
        <common:name>University of Virginia</common:name>
        <common:address>
            <common:city>Charlottesville</common:city>
            <common:region>Virginia</common:region>
            <common:country>US</common:country>
        </common:address>
    </common:organization>
</education:education>
```

WHen I try to use:

```
simplexml_load_file($file);
print_r($xml);
```

It does not return any nodes.

Looks like the problem is the use of ":" like education:education

Any way to solve that ?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412047/parse-xml-namespaces-with-php-simplexml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412047/parse-xml-namespaces-with-php-simplexml) might help

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the expected output?