# Find tags of SimpleXMLElement using xpath

Tags: php, xml

I try to get all BrowseNodeId of the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01">
<OperationRequest>
    <RequestId>00ffd0c4-65b8-40ed-96b3-dbee109c508e</RequestId>
    <Arguments>
        <Argument Name="Condition" Value="All"></Argument>
        <Argument Name="region" Value="com"></Argument>
    </Arguments>
    <RequestProcessingTime>0.0428190000000000</RequestProcessingTime>
</OperationRequest>
<Items>
    <Request>
        <IsValid>True</IsValid>
        <ItemSearchRequest>
            <Condition>All</Condition>
            <Keywords>0321185587</Keywords>
            <ResponseGroup>BrowseNodes</ResponseGroup>
            <SearchIndex>Books</SearchIndex>
        </ItemSearchRequest>
    </Request>
    <TotalResults>1</TotalResults>
    <TotalPages>1</TotalPages>
    <Item>
    <ASIN>0321185587</ASIN>
    <BrowseNodes>
        <BrowseNode>
            <BrowseNodeId>21</BrowseNodeId>
            <Name>Reference</Name>
                <Children>
                    <BrowseNode>
                        <BrowseNodeId>11444</BrowseNodeId>
                        <Name>Almanacs &amp; Yearbooks</Name>
                    </BrowseNode>
                    <BrowseNode>
                        <BrowseNodeId>11448</BrowseNodeId>
                        <Name>Atlases &amp; Maps</Name>
                    </BrowseNode>
                    <BrowseNode>
                        <BrowseNodeId>2572</BrowseNodeId>
                        <Name>Careers</Name>
                    </BrowseNode>
                </Children>
        </BrowseNode>
    </BrowseNodes>
    </Item>
</Items>
</ItemSearchResponse>
```

Here is the PHP code I used:

```
$xml= simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//BrowseNode') as $node) {
      echo $node->BrowseNodeId.":".$node->Name."<br>";
}
```

But the result is NULL. I am not good at XML so I cannot figure out where I was wrong. Can anybody show me the correct xpath syntax for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your document has no nodes named `BrowseNode` in the NULL-namespace.

Instead is has nodes named `BrowseNode` in the `http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01` namespace.

To access these nodes via xpath, you need to register a prefix for that namespace first:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace(
    "prefix", 
    "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01"
);
```

You then can use that *prefix* in the xpath query:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//prefix:BrowseNode') as $node) {
    echo $node->BrowseNodeId, ":", $node->Name, "\n";
}
```

(you for sure can give that *prefix* a different name so it says more, perhaps "`awsecs`", but that is up to you).

You will then get the expected result:

```
21:Reference
11444:Almanacs & Yearbooks
11448:Atlases & Maps
2572:Careers
```

This has been earlier answered in [xPath finds nothing but *](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3719616/367456) and similar.

Comment: It works well. Thank you, @hakre. I always search stackoverflow before asking. The point is I didn't know where I was wrong so I couldn't find the relevant answers.

Comment: that xmlns is called XMLS Namespaces - every attribute or element that start with XML is special.

Comment: Thank you this helped me greatly!